# Vee validate message in an extend async rule fails to show error message

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

Am using vee validate with vuetify and i need to check if email is unique. 
So in my vuejs i have added

```
mounted(){

       extend('unique-email', (value) => {
         return this.$axios.post('/api/auth/unique-email', { email: value })
         .then((res) => {
          return {
            valid: true,
          };
        }, (err) => {
          return {
            valid: false,
            data: { message: 'Email already registered' }
          };
        })
        }, {
         immediate: false
       })
   }
```

In my vuetify i have added

```
<v-textfield v-model="form.email" rules="required|email|unique-emai">
```

The above works for all the rules but doesnt resolve the message `email already registred` from the unique-email rule. What do i need to add so that if the async validation fails the message from the err part is displayed.

Currently it only shows `email is not valid` message when the unique-email validator fails.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/server-side-validation.html#setting-errors-manually), it seems that you need to manually handle errors produced by your POST call, so instead of just returning an object in your error handler, you would do this:

```
   extend('unique-email', (value) => {
     return this.$axios.post('/api/auth/unique-email', { email: value })
     .then((res) => {
      return {
        valid: true,
      };
    }, (err) => {
      this.$refs.myValidationObserver.setErrors({
         email: ['Email already registered']
      });
    })
    }, {
     immediate: false
   })
```

This requires two changes beyond the extend:

1. add the attribute `vid="message"` to your ValidationProvider (VP) around your `v-textfield`
2. add the attribute `ref="myValidationObserver"` to your ValidationObserver that wraps the VP in point #1.

Or, maybe I'm missing something!  Where did you get the idea to return the object that you had in the question?  I can't see anything like that in the current docs...

```
      return {
        valid: false,
        data: { message: 'Email already registered' }
      };
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you forget to collect error information，such like：

```
extend('unique-email', (value) => {
  return this.$axios.post('/api/auth/unique-email', { email: value })
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        valid: true,
      };
    }, (err) => {
      return {
        valid: false,
        data: { message: 'Email already registered' }
      };
    })
  }, 
  getMessage: (field, params, data) => data.message
)
```

btw, "immediate: false" is default, you don't need to explicitly define it.